# php pagination when images are got from a folder

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to put some pagination when displaying images from a folder. However, so far, I can't achieve the result. I have the code to the button next and previously it was working perfectly. Display images was working perfectly as well. But the limit of 8 images per page doesn't work.

this is the code for the images display:

```
<div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <?php
                    $folder = "Products/";
                    if(is_dir($folder)){
                        if($handle = opendir($folder)){
                            while(($file = readdir($handle)) != False){
                                if($file=='.' || $file==='..' ) continue;
                                echo '
                                       <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                            <div class="thumbnail see" href="#">
                                            <!-- para aadicionar titulo data-title= -->
                                                <a href="Products/'.$file.'" data-lightbox="gallery"><img class="img-responsive"
                                                src="Products/'.$file.'" alt="'.$file.'" style="min-height:50px;height:100px;"></a>
                                            </div>
                                       </div>';
                            }
                            closedir($handle);
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And this is the code for pagination:

```
$selectIdImage = mysqli_query($dbc,"Select idImage from images ");
$count_num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($selectIdImage);
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#","",$_GET['page']);
}else{
    $page = 1;
}
$ProductPerPage = 8;
$lastPage = ceil($count_num_rows/$ProductPerPage);

if($page < 1 ){
    $page = 1;
}elseif($page > $lastPage){
    $page = $lastPage;
}
$pagination = '';
$limit = "LIMIT".($page -1).$ProductPerPage.",$ProductPerPage";
if($lastPage !=1){
    if($page != $lastPage){
        $next = $page + 1;
        $pagination.= '<li class="next"><a href="seeProducts.php?page='.$next.'">Next <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span></a></li>';
    }
    if($page != 1){
        $prev = $page - 1;
        $pagination.= '<li class="previous"><a href="seeProducts.php?page='.$prev.'"><span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span> Previous</a></li>';
    }
}
?>
```

So I want 8 images per page but I can't do that. I know how to do if was extract from Database(just put a limit), but from a folder i don't know how to do....

Comment: The question isn't specific enough, please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i have the images with the code, but what i'm trying to do is display for example 8 images per page, when the page for example seeImages.php have the 8 images go to the next page (seeImages.php?page=2) with new 8 more images pressing the button next that i have

Comment: You're not supposed to include your code as image. For at least two reasons: 3rd party websites that store the images can delete them in the future and make this question impossible to understand, 2. How can I copy&paste part of your code into my answer?

Comment: you are right, just put the code like you said, now if you can help i appreciate that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some mistake in the limit:

```
$limit = "LIMIT ".(($page -1)*$ProductPerPage).",$ProductPerPage";
```

As for the files, you can for example collect all the files to an array:

```
                $folder = "Products/";
                $files = array();
                if(is_dir($folder)){
                    if($handle = opendir($folder)){
                        while(($file = readdir($handle)) != False){
                            if($file=='.' || $file==='..' ) continue;
                            $files[] = $file;
                        }
                        closedir($handle);
                    }
                }
```

Note: I think the files will come in a random order, not in ABC, and it is also possible that the order will change when you do certain directory operations (add new files for example), so it might be wise to sort $files:

```
                sort($files);
```

And only print those that should be on the requested page:

```
                for ($i=($page-1)*$ProductPerPage;$i<count($files)&&$i<$page*$ProductPerPage; $i++) {
                            $file = $files[$i];
                            echo '
                                   <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                        <div class="thumbnail see" href="#">
                                            <a href="Products/'.$file.'" data-lightbox="gallery"><img class="img-responsive"
                                            src="Products/'.$file.'" alt="'.$file.'" style="min-height:50px;height:100px;"></a>
                                        </div>
                                   </div>';
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: didn't work..... but thank you anyway.... I think my problem is the position of the display inside the pagination loop, but I'm not sure

Comment: maybe you should show us the continuation of your code where you use $limit to create the query

Comment: That is the problem when i get the images from the folder(first code), I don't know where I should call the variable $limit...... I see a lot of tutorials about this but the majority is about extract data from sql and after paginate them, and that way i know how to do